# JDeveloper 12.2.1.2 configuration for spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jdeveloper

We are swapping between intellij idea project to JDeveloper (not funny :( )
And I have to configure JDeveloper for it.

For now I installed tomcat extension http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/resource/TomcatExtension_11.1.2.zip
and Installed Spring support via Help > Check for updates

I'm looking for some tutorial/Documentation/blog post etc how to configure JDeveloper for technologies like maven, spring, tomcat, hibernate, js.

Do you guys have any ideas or experience?

All what I can find on internet is already deprecated(For example from 2006) or in Brazilian language

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JDeveloper are you using?
JDev 12.2.1 has maven built in.
To get Spring and Hibernate in just click the tools->manage libraries and add libraries with the right jar files.
Then add these libraries to the project properties for the projects that require them.